# Cmake cannot link to static library

Tags: c++, cmake, static-linking

I have the following project structure:

```
ProjectRoot
|           CMakeLists.txt
+---tests
|           CMakeLists.txt
+---tinyxml2
|           CMakeLists.txt
+---transaction
|           CMakeLists.txt
+---xmlGenerator
\-      CMakeLists.txt
```

The root cmakelist is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4)
project(customProject)


include_directories(tinyxml2 transaction)

add_subdirectory(tinyxml2)
add_subdirectory(transaction)
add_subdirectory(tests)
add_subdirectory(xmlGenerator)
```

The tinyxml2 CmakeLists.txt is provided by the library author.
The transaction CMakeLists.txt is:

```
add_library(product product.cpp product.h)

add_library(transaction transaction.cpp transaction.h)
```

The test CMakeLists.txt is:
    add_executable(market_lib_test test.cpp)

```
target_link_libraries (market_lib_test tinyxml2static product transaction )
```

And the xmlGenerator CMakeLists.txt is:
    add_executable(generator generator.cpp)

```
target_link_libraries(generator product tinyxml2static)
```

CMake runs without errors, but when I try to compile the generator target in visual studio I get the following:

> Error 1   error LNK1104: cannot open file
>   '..\transaction\Debug\product.lib'    C:\Users\username\Projects\customProject\build\xmlGenerator\LINK    generator

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does `..\transaction\Debug\product.lib` exist? Did the build succeed for product?

Comment: Yes the product builds without a problem. I cannot answer the second question. I do not know that is the .. part in the path that you quote.